# Large Scale EXT JS application

Tags: extjs

I am starting a large scale EXT JS application and wanted to know if anyone knows of any helpful resources. Everything i've seen up to this point has been a single page application. I would like to use MVC for the front end. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you want use multiple pages? Not that it is not possible. But you will not need to.

Answer (score 6):

@Sra's comment is the most appropriate response here.

Regarding 'single page applications' then can certainly be used for larger scale projects, but careful management of code and the DOM is needed.

I think you might need to provide a bit more information about how you're planning to do things and what you're worried about.

Ext offers a client side MVC implementation but this does tend to centre around the single page application model. What this means is that you write your models, views and controllers and let your app decide which to render. 
The app is responsible for creating and disposing of client side controller and view instances, and the models really just exist to validate data and provide a sensible mechanism for sending / retrieving data from the server side.

If you're wanting to use a typical server side MVC implementation e.g. ASP.NET MVC, then it should be noted that unless the app is massive, you'll probably just end up with a single .NET 'view', this view will contain your entire ExtJS app.

You 'can' if you want, create a series of mini apps via Ext and render those in several server side views, but you will end up with a lot of duplicated (or shared) code which may well be a pain to manage.

So to sum up, yes, you can use Ext for larger applications, yes you can use MVC (both client and server side) and finally yes, your front end will likely form a single page application.

Comment: I think there isn't anything missing +1

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit to the @dougajmcdonald's excellent answer: there are improvements to MVC architecture and dependency handling coming up in Ext JS 4.2, that are specifically aimed at folks with big apps on their hands. It will be a *lot* easier to share code between related applications, which would also make writing multi-page apps easier as well.

Comment: Interesting stuff, will certainly keep an eye on what sencha are producing and how it can be more easily applied to enterprise type solutions.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?253467-Ext-JS-4.2.0-Beta-2-Now-Available :)

Answer (score -4):

EXTjs is not supposed to be coded in single page. EXTjs 4 supports MVC architecture.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/application_architecture

please sencha command also. it helps you to create a backbone of MVC application

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command

Comment: The extjs documentation is a big-single-page application: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/

Comment: it is a single page documentation. But its coding is not done in single page style.

Comment: what keenan is asking is about MVC architecture style coding

Comment: Your answer is missleading